# Can't run locust in debug mode

Tags: python, locust

Recently I switched from old locust version (0.14.2) to 1.3.1. Previously I was able to run in debug mode with command WebsiteUser().run() and it stops on all breakpoints.

When I try to run new version with the same command I get next error:

File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/my_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 210, in **init**
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environment'

I am sure that it's possible to debug new version as previous one, but what I am doing wrong?

#### Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Python version: 3.7.4
- Locust version: 1.3.1
- Locust command line that you ran: WebsiteUser().run()
- Locust file contents:

**locustfile.py:**

```
class UserBehaviour(MyTask):

    @task
    def task_one(self):
        self.action_one()


class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    conf = Config()
    host = conf.host
    tasks = [UserBehaviour]
    wait_time = between(0.5, 1.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WebsiteUser().run()
```

**my_task.py:**

```
class MyTask(BaseTaskSet):

    def action_one(self):
        self.client.get('dummy_path')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Locust 1.0+ has more robust support for [using Locust as a library](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html). It enables a lot more flexibility and customization in using Locust but there were a number of breaking changes to achieve this (one reason for the 1.0 designation). What you're hitting is Locust now requires an [Environment](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?#environment-class) for all `Users` and associated classes. What you'll probably want to do is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from locust.env import Environment
    my_env = Environment(user_classes=[WebsiteUser])
    WebsiteUser(my_env).run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fix everything!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
class WebsiteUser()
```

without an `HttpUser` argument.

You have to use like this:

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

Locust now provides the [`run_single_user`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=debug#locust.debug.run_single_user) function for this purpose.